# Where do I get a shovel?

Tags: stardew-valley

I see these mounds of dirt everywhere and I figure I need a shovel to pick them up as I have tried every other tool (axe, hoe, pickaxe) to try and get to it but none of them have worked.

[image]

I believe that you can dig them up as one of the NPC's say so.

So where can I find a shovel, or other method of digging?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no shovel in the game and that mound of dirt was just a rock. It doesn't do anything.

The NPC was referring to dig spots.[image]

The small black worms in front of me are a dig spot that can be dug with a hoe. Dig spots can contain valuable items, including books and museum artifacts. They're a little easier to spot in-game, since they're animated.

Comment: According to “Livin' Off The Land” they're “wiggling stems,” not worms. (I always thought they were worms too.) I guess they're related to the other background plants that mysteriously are able to bop to the music.